# Cannot add extension with name NAME, as there is an extension already registered with that name

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

**Question:** 
Is it possible to add different plugins with different purposes which resolve to the same name?

**Example:**

```
plugins {
    …
    id("org.owasp.dependencycheck") version "5.2.4"
    id("dependency.check") version "0.0.6"
}
```

which results to following exception:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dependency.check', version: '0.0.6']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'dependency.check']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'dependencyCheck', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

Is there any known or possible work around I could apply to resolve this name conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, no. You would have to conditionally apply one and not the other, e.g. based on a property or command line parameter, if you really want to go down that route.

But are you aware that the second plugin (`dependency.check`) is an old fork of the first (`org.owasp.dependencycheck`)? It doesn't even look like it has any changes compared to the main repository, except that it hasn't been updated in four years.

It doesn't really make any to have two variants of the same plugin in the same project. You should delete the old one.

Comment: It looked to me that dependency.check was not about checking CVEs but rather if the used library is the latest available which org.owasp.dependencycheck doesn't do reading the documentation

Comment: Ah, makes sense. You are probably looking for https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.ben-manes.versions then.